# Помогите разобраться с задачей?

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с задачей. Понимаю для многих это легко, но я что то не могу сообразить. Как объединить два условия для переменных с циклом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста именно как связать эти условия для числа и степени с циклом. а дальше сам цикл и арифметику я уже буду додумывать сам. Или это все делать через цикл do while и в while прописывать четыре условия?

Comment: Текст не надо скриншотом :) Приложите текстом в вопрос

Comment: JS уже начиная с 5-го класса в школьной программе?

Comment: Макс к  возводить в степень не проблема. я немогу понять как связать условие с циклом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эт если по тексту.

```js
let number = 5, degree = 3;
    
if(!Number.isNaN(number) && number !== 0
&& !Number.isNaN(degree) && degree >= 2) {
  let temp = number;
  for(let i = 1; i < degree; i++) {
    temp *= number;
  }
  alert(number+'^'+degree+'='+temp);
}
```

---

А так в идеале - [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```js
let number = 5, degree = 3;
console.info(number+'^'+degree+'='+Math.pow(number,degree));
```

Comment: Спасибо. я и хотел использовать Math.pow(), но запнулся именно на том ка совместить условие и цикл.